# How to read batch file in azure blob within azure function using a loop

Tags: azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I want to read the multiple model files in blob storage when I use azure function HTTPTrigger. And within **init**.py file in the function projects folder, I want to write a loop to process the data using all the models and save the results back to blob storage. So how can I get access to all the models file and read them in the **init**.py?

Right now I modify the function.json file, which refer to certain blob's file and it work for one models. Here is the code:

```
{
  "type": "blob",
  "name": "inputblob",
  "path": "models/model_name.pickle",
  "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage", 
  "direction": "in"
}
```

Here we specify the file name and the parameter name of it, it works but for multi models file, how can I manage that? It is not sufficient top create so many JavaScripts lick that.

Comment: did you manage to get this done?

Answer (score 0):

The blob input binding handles one blob per binding; you'll need to use the `azure-storage-package` to retrieve multiple blobs from storage. Take a look at the [steps of this quickstart article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python#list-the-blobs-in-a-container) for an example.